# sticky sidebar not working during scrolling

Tags: html, jquery, css

I want to have a sticky sidebar during scrolling  and I have tried many methods but it is not working. here is my code

```
 <div class="row">

        <div class="col me-0 me-md-3 mb-3 mb-md-0 px-0 ">

            <div class="position-relative" style="top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;


                <div class="bg-white b-r-s-cont shadow pb-4 position-sticky top-0">
               height: 100%;">
         </div>
         </div>
      </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-9">
       </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try adding `position: fixed;` to the element that is supposed to be sticky.

You can simply add it it the current `style="..."` tag!

Comment: thank u for your help, but if I use position: fixed it is going to be fixed in the page but I need to make it stick to the element above the wanted sticky div as you can see in my code

Comment: Well, your code has several problems so it's hard to determine what your actual problem is. First of, you have a div in a style tag, which already is wrong and cant work. Other than that, if you want an element to be always sticking with another one, why don't you just put it in the div that you want it to stick to?